# facebook access_token format changed suddenly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, access-token

Our application get the facebook session_key from the access_token, but I found the access_token format was changed today, the return value of the access_token without the delimiter '|', I can't get the session_key with the new format, please help me.

Here is the new access_token:
AAACNiIlBuO0BACgjrbFp1a8dAUxP4t0ojVElFA88aJFVxG3gISvETafwEUzbMzLPxAVcTUWXyUJaBgy1OxBQHdneW1v0ZD

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts, you now have full control over your questions and answers. In the future, please edit your question if you want to add more information, or use the comment facilities under the answers you receive to leave comments. You might consider associating an OpenID with your account, so you don't keep losing the cookie that is currently bound to your current account.

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is, the "OAuth Migration" setting in app settings was enabled, it will return an encrypted access token.

Comment: Hello Owen... The setting "OAuth Migration" is not available in the advance page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/145094738849065/advanced

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is named fbsr_*APP-ID* and it contains the signed request. 
When you parse that signed request you will not immediately get the acces token but a code that needs to be authenticated again with facebook. The method is almost the same as with the signed request from the standard login but not quite. The redirect_uri must be an empty string. And any " need to be removed. The user id is still directly available in the signed request:

```
{u'issued_at': 1316611903, 
 u'code': u'2.AQB0gn0ueVWMpj-c.3600.1316617200.1-684450912|RTJur1Zmr__4d4uX5vg25tc1X4M', 
 u'user_id': u'*USER-ID*', u'algorithm': u'HMAC-SHA256'}
```

The response from the authentication changed as well. Before it was a URL-Encoded string containing the access token. Now it also contains an expires value: The amount of seconds the token is valid. It looks something like this:

```
access_token="AAADYZBFNocBMBAK8Z.....2CljZAk1xX4rd9quEoXTygZDZD"&expires=6295
```